# CSS Границы элемента при его трансформации

Tags: css, css3

Здравствуйте.
Если к элементу применить CSS свойство `transform: rotate(45deg)` он развернется, но положение в потоке не изменит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы границы блока пересчитались и рассчитывались по углам, например так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: transform-origin

Comment: @Elena он же изменит точку относительно которой объект вращается, но габариты блока останутся

Comment: тогда добавляйте tranlsate

Comment: @Elena  мне не сдвинуть надо его, а что бы его размер пересчитался, если сейчас у него размеры 200х200, то после трансформации размеры стали 282.84х282.84. Или такое средствами CSS невозможно?

Comment: простите, не поняла вопрос)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `.getBoundingClientRect()` всегда возвращает актуальные габариты элемента, в т. ч. после трансформации. Нам понадобятся его свойства `width` и `height`. Чтобы центр вращения всегда был внутри внешней обертки нам надо выровнять его по вертикали и горизонтали, для этого поставим обертке свойство `display: inline-flex`, а самому элементу `margin: auto`. Далее, при каждом вращении будем устанавливать ширину и высоту вращаемого элемента обертке.

```js
let rotationAngle = 0,
    el = document.querySelector('.el'),
    wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

recalcDimensions(30);
document.querySelector('.rotator').addEventListener('click', recalcDimensions.bind("", 5));

function recalcDimensions(rotateAngle) {      
  rotationAngle += rotateAngle;
  
  el.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotationAngle + "deg)";
    
  let w = el.getBoundingClientRect().width,
      h = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      
  wrapper.style.width = w + 'px';
  wrapper.style.height = h + 'px';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.el {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.rotator {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=el></div>
</div>

<button class=rotator>rotate me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

div::after,
div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div::after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
}

div::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.70711356, .70711356);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: А откуда коэффициенты скейла? Подогнали вручную?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko вы издеваетесь? слова "теорема Пифагора" ничего не говорят?